# Cannot compile c++ project with opencv and dlib libraries in vs16

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, dlib

This is my code in vs project:

```
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/render_face_detections.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <dlib/opencv/cv_image_abstract.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/photo.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

struct correspondens {
    std::vector<int> index;
};
void faceLandmarkDetection(dlib::array2d<unsigned char>& img, shape_predictor sp, std::vector<Point2f>& landmark) {...}

void delaunayTriangulation(const std::vector<Point2f>& hull, std::vector<correspondens>& delaunayTri, Rect rect) {...}

void applyAffineTransform(Mat& warpImage, Mat& src, std::vector<Point2f>& srcTri, std::vector<Point2f>& dstTri) {...}

void warpTriangle(Mat& img1, Mat& img2, std::vector<Point2f>& t1, std::vector<Point2f>& t2) {...}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {...}
```

But after compiling I get these errors:

```
1>FaceSwapper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external character USER_ERROR__inconsistent_build_configuration__see_dlib_faq_2.
1>C:\Users\Snusm\Desktop\codes\Projects\Try\x64\Release\Try.exe : fatal error LNK1120: unresolved external elements: 11
1>The build of the "Try.vcxproj" project failed with an error.
```

This program find 11 similar errors with external character
What can this be related to and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do not post images of console output, post the text.  And please translate the error into English to widen the audience who can help you.

Comment: Did  you `input` the corresponding lib file correctly?

Comment: In the project's settings?

Comment: Yes. It is a linking error.

Comment: In input I write: **dlib19.23.0_release_64bit_msvc1929.lib**
**opencv_world455d.lib**. As in the libraries' files

Comment: Did you read the dlib faq as hinted in the error message?

Comment: I don't understand a little where I can read it

Comment: You seem to be mixing debug lib and release lib.

Comment: You mean I use opencv and dlib in different versions. One of them in release other in debug?

Comment: Ok, I change release on debug and no more old errors but I take one new:
**
C:\lib\dlib-19.23\source\dlib\all\source.cpp : fatal error C1128: number of sections exceeded object file format limit: compile with /bigobj
1>Done building project "Try.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The solution is again in the error message, add `/bigobj` to your compiler options

Comment: Thanks for helping, I've already solved my problem using yours advises

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to know your problem was solved. The key to solving the problem  is to use the same version of the library and compile with `/bigobj`. The [document C1128](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1128?view=msvc-170) also points out:

> To correct this error, divide your source file into multiple source
> code files, compile without /Gy, or compile with /bigobj